# Invalid value for field(s) : Individual Prefix

Tags: drupal

I am importing a new database into CiviCRM using the CSV import method in: Contacts > Import Contacts. In the downloaded CSV file with the list of errors, I get next error for a lot of entries:

```
Invalid value for field(s) : Individual Prefix
```

I suppose it is related to the list of prefixes I introduced in: Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Dropdown Options > Individual Prefixes

In the CSV file used for importing the contacts, I put the *value* corresponding to the dropdown option. The error above is caused by a lot of entries with "2" as value, when there is actually an option with value "2" present in the different options available.

I wonder what could be the cause this error.

Comment: Hi... I don't think the value field has to be unique in the table so it's worth checking if there's two entries for the same group with the value of '2' or try the import with field label or name.

Comment: Value '2' is unique in the table, so the problem may be elsewhere. Anyway, I will try to import the records with the field label, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using option label over value, i know its weird but for some options value doesn't work but label does or vice versa.